# how to fetch data in loop from nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, fetch

i have this array available

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
     [0] => FL 
     [1] => members 
    ) 
[1] => Array (
     [0] => FK 
     [1] => members
    ) 
[2] => Array (
     [0] => number 
     [1] => number 
    ) 
[3] => Array (
      [0] => FV 
      [1] => mem 
    ) 
)
```

and I want to fetch this data as

```
 FL FK number FV
 members members number mem
```

I have given this data as an input field and want to show this as input too
example
input is given from:
http://prntscr.com/1r6p4y1
and want the output as same as the input given in these fields

I have tried this code:

```
   foreach($project_fields as $k => $detail){
                    foreach ($detail as $key => $value) {
                         
                        echo '<li class="detail_list"> &nbsp; <label>'.(isset($detail)? $value : $value ).' &nbsp;  ';

                        echo " ".' </label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="project_fields[label][]" value="'.$value.'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="project_fields[key][]" value="'.$custom_details[$k].'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="project_fields[type][]" class="privacy_select" value="'.(isset($project_fields['type'][$k])?$project_fields['type'][$k]:'all').'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="project_fields[value][]" value="'.$project_fields['value'][$k].'" />
                        <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span></li>';
                    
                    }
                }
```

but it is returning this:

http://prntscr.com/1r6ppzg

i want it like:

```
FL FK number FV
 members members number mem
```

anyone can help will appreciatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is multidimensional, You can store the data in 2 different arrays and again show as per your need.

Here is example as per your output,

```
foreach ($your_array as $value) {
    $array1[] = $value[0];
    $array2[] = $value[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1) . "<br/>";
print_r($array2) . "<br/>";
```